# How to trigger function when press "Enter" on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

How may I trigger the button callback function of the test function when the user presses "Enter" on the phone's keyboard?

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textfield.delegate = self 
    }

    @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
        //textfield.resignFirstResponder()
        label.text = textfield.text!
        print("\n func completed \n")
    }

    func test(textField: UITextField!) {
        textfield.resignFirstResponder()
        print("\n func completed \n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it directly

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {    
   textField.resignFirstResponder() // options 1
   self.test(textField)  // option 2
   self.calledFromAnyWhere() // option 3  
   return true
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to call the button's action it's preferred to make a shared function

```
 @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {

   self.calledFromAnyWhere()
}

func calledFromAnyWhere()
{
    // any content
}
```

Comment: You really should not pass a dummy button to the `btn` method. What if that method needs to update the state of the button? Really, you should not be directly calling the `btn` method. If some code needs to be called from both a button handler and a text field delegate, then that code should be put in another method that both the button handler and the text field delegate call.

Comment: I agree but if you read the remaining part of comment i'm telling him to send the btn name if it's really exists , also i will refactor for sake correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add target to handle the specific events, as such:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingDidEnd), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)


@objc func editingDidEnd() {
    // Do whatever you would like here, in your case
    self.btnCallback()
}
```